# Разработка проекта вдвоем

Tags: git

Добрый день.
Раньше я работал один с github. Но теперь появилась потребность вместе с приятелем работать над проектом. Не могу понять, ведь если приятель сделал push, то я уже не могу сделать push, пока сам не загружу обновления. Возможно, придется создать ветви, потом межрить их в конце дня, перед работой pull, потом опять мержить, допонимаю.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в таких случаях организовывается работа?

1) Т.е. в начале работы делаю так:

```
git init  
git clone url
```

Скачал проект.

2) Сделал изменения и:

```
git add. 
git commit -m "comment"
git push remote feature/create-feedback-form
```

Отправили в репозиторий.

3) Кто-то мержит ветки разработчиков вечером.

4) Утром каждый разработчик делает pull в свою ветку и работает. Как закончит работать, производит второй этап и т.д.

Так?

Comment: @ks_on_v, я это все уже писал вообще-то

> git push remote feature/create-feedback-form отправили в репозиторий.

нет, локальные ветки никуда не уходят

> Утром каждый разработчик делает pull в свою ветку

свои ветки у них исключительно локальные, неоткуда пулл делать

> Кто-то мержит ветки разработчиков вечером.

Сам разработчик. В тот момент, когда таск дописан, он мерджится с dev и коммит-мердж отправляется в репу. Бывают такие люди как релиз-менеджеры, которые следят за ветками release и master и никто кроме них туда пушить не может. Но просто мердж таска в общую ветвь - задача разраба.

Comment: Спасибо, что помогаете разобраться.
А dev - локальный

Comment: @ks_on_v нет, не локальный. Это видно, например, вот [здесь](http://screencloud.net/v/tpHZ) или [здесь](http://screencloud.net/v/yedT).

Comment: Да я пытаюсь с командами гита разобраться. push это залить, если можно мержить, посути тоже залить в другую ветвь...
Пока я понял, что есть ветви в самом репозитории master - рабочий проект, dev - ежедневно закидываются наработки разрабом. Сам разраб пишет в своей локальной ветви, потом мержит в dev. А когда разраб садится снова писать он же должен скачать обновления, замерженные его саратником, это pill-ом делается?

Comment: @ks_on_v, да. Суть в том, что для каждого разработчика доступна удаленная ветвь dev (пусть master и release в примере управляются совсем другими людьми), которая представляет собой некий пул обновлений. Он не может напрямую в ней работать (физически может, но лучше этого не делать), но он может почковать из нее локальные ветки и мерджить их обратно в dev, и, соответственно, подтягивать изменения dev и заливать свои изменения этой ветки в репозиторий, принятый за общий.

Comment: Вот вариант, который снизу хороший.  Мы сейчас с другом разрабатываем одну штуку. Там нам сильно заморачиваться не надо, поэтому у нас просто есть ветка develop, а есть у каждого своя - vasya, alex, например. Когда что-то готово, мы просто из своей ветки создаем pull request и вливаем в develop, после чего обновляем свою ветку из develop.

Comment: Аааааа, репозитория 2 (локальный и удаленный). Т.е. каждый разработчик делает add или комитит у себя на локалке сколько хочет, но в конце дня он мержит свию локальную ветвь dev с удаленной master? А наутро делает pull из удаленной master и работает дальше?

Comment: @ks_on_v, посмотрите, пожалуйста, ссылку на гитфлоу. Нет, никто не мержит просто так с мастером. Мы уже обсудили, что в этой ветке только стабильные доделанные релизы.

Разработчик мержит **локальную** ветвь в dev, после чего отправляет обновления ветки dev в удаленный репозиторий, расшаривая таким образом свою работу. Перед началом и закрытием таска он подтягивает (pull) обновления dev.

Цикл разработки - не день, а одна задача. Сделали задачу - мерджим - отправляем в репо. Не делаем этого - получаем миллиард конфликтов к концу дня и задерживаемся на работе на два часа.

Answer (score 2):

Классическая схема удаленного репозитория:

- **master** - здесь валяются **исключительно** рабочие версии проекта.
- **dev** - относительно стабильная ветка, в которую закидываются все законченные обновления
- **release-XXX** или **rc** (часто его роль выполняет dev) - ветка подготовки к следующему релизу. В большинстве случаев этой ветки не существует, но мне она симпатична тем, что в ней можно спокойно собирать следующий релиз, в то время как в **dev** можно пихать обновления, заглядывая на пару milestone'в вперед. Впрочем, в этом случае поддержка всего флоу становится на порядок сложнее. Git-flow рекомендует наличие релизных веток.
- другие публичные ветки, специфичные для каждого проекта

Все законченные версии проекта обязательно тегируются.

Классическая схема работы с локальным репозиторием ([git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)):

- Каждый чих, каждый таск оформляется в виде ветки **feature/XXX**, отпочковавшейся от **dev**. Это позволяет в любой момент вернуться к просто **dev** или **master**, чтобы закрыть баг исходя из текущего состоянии проекта и не пихать туда незаконченные обновления.
- Хотфиксы оформляются как **hotfix/XXX** и по завершении мержатся и в **dev**, и в **master**
- При необходимости эти ветки публикуются на сервере, а по завершению удаляются.

Такой подход позволяет более атомарно подходить к реализуемым таскам, заставляет дева заниматься разрешением конфликта до того, как он начал пушить в репу и уменьшает количество пушей.

Comment: Поправьте меня, правильно ли я вас понял и применил к моей ситуации с двумя разработчиками:
1) Есть главная ветка master, она хранит релиз проекта (не наработки, а уже готовые стадии app). И скажем ветку release, в неё мы будем скидывать (мержить, объединять) ежедневные наработки.
2) Я создаю ветку dev-1 для себя и dev-2 для приятеля.
3) В конце каждого дня (когда работы над проектом не предпологается) я буду мержить ветки dev-1 и dev-2 с release.
4) В начале дня каждый разработчик делает pull в свою ветку и работает.
5) В конце дня опять мержим ветки.
Правильно?

Comment: @ks_on_v не совсем. Dev - это общая ветка. Каждый разработчик с утра сливает обновления всех веток, создает новую ветку **feature/create-feedback-form** (согласно таску), либо открывает вчерашнюю (которая существует только у него в локальном репозитории), завершает работу над таском, мерджит его в dev, и, возможно, release, отправляет в репозиторий, начинает новую итерацию. Разработчикозависимые ветки существуют только в локальных репозиториях (пока не требуется участие других людей, тогда эта ветка публикуется), остальные существует во всех репозиториях, но используются крайне редко.

Comment: Т.е. посути можно пушить всем в одну ветку? Локальные все равно у каждого свои.

Comment: @ks_on_v, да, просто за счет схемы количество пушей знатно уменьшается.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде разобрался. А вот вопрос, я же не смогу сделать push (слить свои локальные изменения с веткой dev), если есть изменения в dev а я не сделал pull (не скачал с репозитория gihub)?

Comment: @ks_on_v, слить - сможете, отправить это на сервер - нет. При появлении такой ситуации надо либо сделать повторный мердж с новоприбывшими коммитами, либо делать pull --rebase, который переместит сделанную работу в конец истории.

Comment: Видимо, я в определениях путаюсь:  
1) слить - добавить в локальный репозиторий - commit? Отравить - это push?
Мердж - объединение веток (применяется только к веткам)?   
2) pull --rebase - сначала скачает с общего, потом запушит в него?

Comment: @ks_on_v

Мердж - да, объединение двух веток.

Слить - смерджить две ветки. Так как формально репозитории могут отличаться только наличием working copy (сейчас неважно, что это), без разницы, где этот мердж происходит.

rebase - механизм, позволяющий перенести коммиты в конец истории, пушить он ничего не будет. Если разработчик слил коммиты A, B, C, добавил D и E и обнаружил, что в репе появились еще F и G, то pull --rebase "исправит" эту историю до состояния A-B-C-F-G-D'-E' (время добавления F и G относительно D и E не играет абсолютно никакого значения). Это позволяет избежать мерджей.

Answer (score -1):

Для начало если вы работаете на одним проектом и у вас 1 цель допилить проект 1 кусок и 2 кусок 
то для этого не нужно создавать ветви!
1 делом нужно сделать pull перед git push патом git status если все отлично просто делаешь git pull!
Перед тем как закидывать тебе и твоему другу делайти git pull скачиваешь его правки а патом закидываешь свои и у вас проблем не будет